# Стрижка 950 рублей! Нужно ли здесь тире?

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис

> Стрижка 950 рублей!

Нужно ли здесь тире? Это неполное предложение?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Тире ставится: ***Стрижка — 950 рублей.***

1) Это двусоставное (двукомпонентное) предложение.

По Грамматике-80  структурная схема  предложения следующая:  N1 —  N1, то есть сущ. в И.п. — сущ. в И.п. Второй компонент выражен числовым оборотом в форме И.п.

**Общее значение** таких предложений — это отношение между субъектом и его предметно представленным признаком. Есть **два типа** таких предложений: 1) предложение содержит **информацию** о субъекте; 2) в предложении субъект характеризуется каким-либо **отношением** (связанности, обусловленности, сопутствия, охвата).

В приведенном примере не содержится информация о субъекте, поэтому нельзя сказать:  Стрижка — это 950р.

Здесь выражено **сопутствующее соотношение** между предметом и его ценой.

Предложение похоже на **эллиптическое**, которое отличается от **неполного** тем, что пропущенное сказуемое понятно по смыслу, а не восстанавливается из предыдущего текста.

Пример предложения: *Цены здесь вполне доступные. Стрижка — 950 рублей.*

2) В то же время надо отличать предложение **от списка цен** (прейскуранта), в котором нет предложений.

Answer (score 1):

Тире нужно.

*950 рублей* — выступает сказуемым.

Розенталь:
Тире ставится, если оба главных члена предложения выражены количественными числительными или если один из них выражен формой именительного падежа существительного, а другой — числительным либо оборотом с числительным:
*Двадцать лет — хорошая вещь.

Расставанья и встречи — две главные части, из которых когда-нибудь сложится счастье.

Трижды пять — пятнадцать.

Скорость — шестьдесят километров в час.*
http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=92

При соответствующем контексте возможно неполное предложение (без повторения сказуемого из предыдущего предложения):
*— Сколько стоит стрижка?*
*— Стрижка 950 рублей!* || Без ударения на первом слове и тире.
или
*Маникюр стоит 1200 рублей, а стрижка — 950 рублей.*

Comment: Стрижка -это 950р.? Как-странно получается тогда.

Comment: Не это, а сколько. Тире ставится, если есть ударение на существительное. А оно точно есть, если это объявление.

Comment: Сказуемое -это то, что говорится о подлежащем. Получается, что стрижка это 950р. Это неполное предложение.

Comment: Так и "говорится о подлежащем" (о том, сколько стрижка стоит). Не обязательно определять понятие стрижки через "это". Можно допустить, что тире вместо пропущенного глагола "стоит".

Comment: Да, верно. Стрижка стоит 950р. Только 950р. это не сказуемое, в определение.